xp_cmdshell and SQL Server replication process
Do enabling/disabling xp_cmdshell has effect on replication setup?
We have transactional replication setup with our SQL Sever 2014.



Do enabling/disabling xp_cmdshell has effect on replication setup?

No. They are independent features.
Also, it's recommended to generally keep xp_cmdshell disabled, from a security best practice standpoint:

xp_cmdshell is a powerful feature and disabled by default.


Yes sir. I too was thinking of the same until I came across the following articles as below,
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4912/is-disabling-xpcmdshell-in-sql-server-really-secure/
https://www.pythian.com/blog/technical-track/distribution-cleanup-job-cant-delete-folder
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/xp_cmdshell-transactional-replication
Attaching a screenshot depicting usage of xp_cmdshell within our DB and I am seeing results with 'repl' 'distribution' subscription' 'publisher' kind of words. So thought to check with it.
